# teamcity with grunt protractor

Tags: selenium, teamcity, protractor

After tons of troubleshooting I finally got selenium to run but it just starts the server and sits on it. Anybody have any idea how to make it run the tests and exit?

```
[Step 9/9] Executing /home/ubuntu/buildAgent/work/d653d615082dd19f/node_modules/.bin/grunt via wrapping shell script
[16:47:57][Step 9/9] Starting: /home/ubuntu/buildAgent/temp/agentTmp/wrapper3464043714269626324.sh --no-color --teamcity.properties.all=/home/ubuntu/buildAgent/temp/agentTmp/teamcity7605733587545998535.json --teamcity.properties=/home/ubuntu/buildAgent/temp/agentTmp/teamcity414610972945921232.json protractor
[16:47:57][Step 9/9] in directory: /home/ubuntu/buildAgent/work/d653d615082dd19f
[16:48:01][Step 9/9] Running "protractor:myApp" (protractor) task
[16:48:01][Step 9/9] Starting selenium standalone server...
[16:48:01][Step 9/9] [launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[16:48:02][Step 9/9] Selenium standalone server started at http://172.30.0.51:40590/wd/hub
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is a service, which "starts and runs" :) This is the purpose of Selenium as well as any other service.

If you want to run Protractor tests which runs their own Selenium service, then you should just set Selenium jar and do not set the Selenium address.

```
export.config = {
  // Excerpt of protractor.conf.js

  seleniumServerJar: 'node_modules/protractor/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar',
  // Comment out seleniumAddress
  // seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI People. I had the same use case and I needed the selenium process to close after all the tests were executed.

I wrote a simple **power shell** script which is what I ended up using later.

```
# Check if chrome driver is already running.

$java = Get-Process java*

Write-Host $java

if ($java) {           
    $java | Stop-Process -Force
}
```

This is obviously not the best script I could write but then it did the job. You can use process Explorer to find that selenium runs on the Java process thread and hence, it is the one you have to kill.

This tiny script is now a part of the build process.